# Spark SQL : is it possible to read the custom schema from an external source instead of creating it in within the spark code?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Trying to load a csv file without schema inference.
Usually we create the schema as StructType within the spark code.
Is it possible to save the schema in an external file (may be a property/config file) and read it dynamically while creating the dataframe ?

```
val customSchema_v2 = new StructType()
  .add("PROPERTY_ID_2222", "int" )
  .add("OWNER_ID_2222", "int")
```

Is it possible to save the schema i.e "PROPERTY_ID_2222", "int" and "OWNER_ID_2222", "int" in a file and call the schema from there ?

Comment: Since you already have a code snippet, you could very well read these values `"PROPERTY_ID_222"` (*column-name*) and `"int"` (*column-type*) from an external file; that would pretty much achieve the same effect as what you want: creating schema from external file. While I don't see any reason why that won't work, [**@LiJianing**'s suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276024/3679900) certainly seems more robust

Answer (score 0):

Both StructType and StructField can Serializable, so you can serialize a StructType to a file and deserialize it when you need

Answer (score -1):

You can use JSON for schemas.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val customSchema_v2 = new StructType()
                         .add("PROPERTY_ID_2222", "int" )
                         .add("OWNER_ID_2222", "int")

val schemaString = customSchema_v2.json

println(schemaString)

val loadedSchema = DataType.fromJson(schemaString)
```

CONSOLE Output:

```
{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"PROPERTY_ID_2222","type":"integer","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"OWNER_ID_2222","type":"integer","nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]}
```

You would need to add code that reads the schema from the JSNO files.

JSON files could also be created manually and can be in pretty format. To understand it better add more columns with different data types and use **customSchema_v2.prettyJson** to lear the syntax.